# Is it possible to turn off required flow annotation?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I would like to use type annotation only for some functions, is it possible to turn off "Missing type annotation for..." error in Flow?

Comment: But what's the point of using flow only for some functions?

Comment: When you want to rely on duck typing for less complex parts of the app to quickly move forward. This is possible e.g. in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable a single line by adding `// $FlowFixMe`, that will ignore the next line